# What are the best biographies Vilna Gaon?

Tags: product-recommendation, vilna-gaon, biography

I watched Henry Abramson's lecture on the Vilna Gaon prepared with the book *The Genius: Elijah of Vilna and the Making of Modern Judaism* by Eliyahu Stern.

The reviews of that book are good, but there are mixed opinions as well. Which biography about the Vilna Gaon has produced the best impression on *you*?

Thanks!

Comment: Close as opinion-based? (I don’t have enough points to actually VTC)

Comment: Academic- The Gaon of Vilna: The Man and His Image

Comment: This may be off topic https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5175/759

Comment: If this isn’t off-topic, it’s fine as normal [tag:product-recommendation] @loani

Comment: @DonielF, an inquiry about intellectual biographies is not a request for a product-recommendation!

Comment: @Oliver How so? Is an intellectual biography not a product, and you're asking for our recommendations on a good one? Even if it's not a perfect parallel, it would still follow the same rules as one in terms of its being on-topic. (I'm trying to help you here and keep your question open!)

Comment: @DonielF, that's much appreciated! I'm basically asking educated opinions, not recommendations, about the relative intellectual worth of scholarly works about a key and very complex figure in Jewish thought. I understand that the product-recommendation section is more for commerce items.

Comment: Oliver, as tagged, this is off-topic, however were you to add the [product-recommendation] tag, it would become on-topic

Comment: I feel that asking about the "best" biography (title) is very opinion-based. Asking about biographies and a short summary of what it contains, how it is different from others, why it made an impression on the reader, etc. are all fine. A product-recommendation tag would also be consistent with other similar questions

Comment: I've closed this as off-topic, which it is. IMO, it also unacceptably seeks opinions in that it doesn't give any criteria for an acceptable biography. If it did, then people could answer with which books meet those criteria; as it is, they can only state which books they find impressive as requested, which is subjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really liked Artscroll's "[The Vilna Gaon: The Life and Teachings of Rabbi Eliyahu the Gaon of Vilna](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0899064418)" by Betzalel Landau.

"[The Vilna Gaon: The Story of Rabbi Eliyahu Kramer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1560622784)" 
by Yaacov Dovid Shulman is another solid option (although I preferred the Artscroll biography).

Answer (score 2):

First, it is surprising that someone would give a lecture based on the book you mentioned given the many inaccuracies in that book, as enumerated [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131212215108/http://seforim.blogspot.com/2013/12/the-vilna-gaon-part-1-how-modern-was-he.html) and [here](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%2016%20Krakowski.pdf). 
For more accurate information about the Vilna Gaon, it would be better to look at *Aliyot Eliyahu* or R. Betzalel Landau's *Ha-Gaon He-Chasid mi-Vilna*. Immanuel Etkes' book, while not a full biography, also provides a better source of information.